# How to prove the generalized associative law for addition on $\mathbb N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, peano-axioms

Let $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ where $n>3$ be a finite sequence in $\mathbb N$. Then there is a sequence $(s_1,\cdots,s_n)$ such that $s_1=a_1$ and $s_{i+1}=s_i+a_{i+1}$ for all $1\leq i<n$ (I proved this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860987/how-to-justify-the-definition-of-summation-s-n-sum-i-1n-a-i-a-1-cdotsa-n)). As a result, we write $s_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$.

I would like to ask how to prove $$a_1+\cdots +a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}+\cdots+a_n=(a_1+\cdots +a_k)+a_{k+1}+(a_{k+2}+\cdots+a_n)$$ with only basic properties of addition, which are listed below.

1. $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$
2. $a+b=b+a$

Please help me with some hints!

Comment: These sums with more than $3$ summands are ambiguous unless we already know what you're trying to prove. You'll need to define what you mean by them. One well-defined way of stating the problem would be to ask whether, if sums of $m$ summands have been defined for all $m\lt n$, the sum of $n$ summands on the left-hand side can equivalently be defined by any of the expressions on the right-hand side independent of the choice of $k$.

Comment: @joriki I have edited to remove such ambiguity. Can you elaborate more on *These sums with more than 3 summands are ambiguous unless we already know what you're trying to prove*. In my common sense, $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=(\cdots((a_1+a_2)+a_3)\cdots)+a_n)$.

Comment: That's just one arbitrary order in which the operations can be formed. It could also mean $a_1+(a_2+\cdots+(a_{n-1}+a_n)\cdots)$. In programming languages, operators are called "left-associative" or "right-associative", respectively, according to which of these conventions apply to them; see [operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). In mathematics, exponentiation is usually assumed to be right-associative, i.e. $\mathrm e^{x^2}$ means $\mathrm e^{(x^2)}$, not $(\mathrm e^x)^2$ (which would make it equal to $\mathrm e^{2x}$).

Comment: @joriki I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

One method is to do this in two steps.

I'll use your convention that + is left-associative:

$$a_1+a_2+⋯+a_n=(⋯((a_1+a_2)+a_3)⋯)+a_n) \tag{*}$$

And of course we have the basic (ungeneralized) associativity of +:

$$(a+b)+c = a + (b + c) \tag{**}$$

First, use induction on $n$ to prove:

**Lemma**

$$a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_n)=a_1+a_2+⋯+a_n$$

Proof:

Base: Trivial

Step:

$$a_1+(a_2+a_3+...+a_k + a_{k+1}) \overset{(*)}{=}$$

$$a_1+((((...((a_2+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1}) \overset{(**)}{=}$$

$$(a_1+(((...((a_2+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1} \overset{(*)}{=}$$

$$(a_1+(a_2+a_3+...+a_k))+a_{k+1} \overset{(I.H)}{=}$$

$$(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_k)+a_{k+1}) \overset{(*)}{=}$$

$$(((...(((a_1+a_2)+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1} \overset{(*)}{=}$$

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1} $$

Then, use induction on $i$ (where during the step you'll use the above Lemma) to prove:

**Theorem**

$$a_1+⋯+ a_{n-i} + a_{n-i+1} + ... + a_n = (a_1+⋯+ a_{n-i}) + (a_{n-i+1} + ... + a_n)$$

This Theorem is equivalent to what you are trying to prove .. it just reindexes things a bit so it lends itself better for an inductive proof

I'll leave working out the details to you, but with this set-up it's not hard.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @Bram28. I almost think that this question will sink into oblivion and no longer receive any answer. On the basis of your hints, I have formalized the proof and posted it as an answer below. Please have a check on it!

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of @Bram28's answer, I present the proof here.

---

*Lemma:* $a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_n)=a_1+a_2+⋯+a_n$

*Proof:* We will prove this by induction on $n$. It's clear that the theorem is trivially true for $n=1$. Assume that it is true for $n=k$, i.e. $a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_k)=a_1+a_2+⋯+a_k$.

We have $a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$

$=a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}))$ [By induction hypothesis]

$=a_1+a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$ [By induction hypothesis]

$=(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$

$=(a_1+a_2)+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}$ [By induction hypothesis]

$=a_1+a_2+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}$.

Thus the theorem is true for $n=k+1$. This completes the proof.

*Theorem:* $a_1+⋯+ a_{n-i} + a_{n-i+1} + ... + a_n = (a_1+⋯+ a_{n-i}) + (a_{n-i+1} + ... + a_n)$

*Proof:* We will prove this by induction on $i$. For $i=1$, the theorem becomes $a_1+a_2+⋯+a_n = (a_1+⋯+ a_{n-1}) + a_n$, and this is trivially true according to our convention. Assume that the theorem is true for $i=k$, i.e. $$a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k} + a_{n-k+1} + ... + a_n = (a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k}) + (a_{n-k+1} + ... + a_n)$$ For $i=k+1$, we have $a_1+⋯+ a_{n-(k+1)} + a_{n-(k+1)+1} + ... + a_n$
$=a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k-1} + a_{n-k} + ... + a_n$
$=(a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k-1} + a_{n-k}) + (a_{n-k+1}+... + a_n)\text{ [By induction hypothesis] }$
$=(a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k-1}) + a_{n-k} + (a_{n-k+1}+... + a_n)$
$=(a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k-1}) + (a_{n-k} + (a_{n-k+1}+... + a_n))\text{ [By Lemma] }$
$=(a_1+⋯+ a_{n-k-1}) + (a_{n-k} + a_{n-k+1}+... + a_n)\text{ [By Lemma] }$
$=(a_1+⋯+ a_{n-(k+1)}) + (a_{n-(k+1)+1}+... + a_n)$

Thus the theorem is true for $i=k+1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: In the proof for the Lemma you use that $a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})=a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}))$, i.e. that $a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})=a_2+(a_3+⋯+(a_k+a_{k+1})...)$, but I thought we used the convention that $a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})=((...(a_2+a_3)+⋯+a_k)+a_{k+1}$

Comment: Hi @Bram28 since there are $k$ elements in the sequence $(a_i\mid 2\leq i\leq k+1)$, I applied induction hypothesis (in which the theorem is true for any sequence of size $n=k$) to get $a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}=a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but my issue is with how you interpret $a_1+a_2+a_3+....+a_n$ (see joriki's comments). I thought you regarded the + as left-associative, and in my proof plan i treated the + as such  when I specified the convention... but in this proof you're treating it as right-associative. ... but then it is trivial that $a_1+(a_2+a_3+...+a_n)=a_1+...+a_n$ for this would simply be true by that very convention!

Comment: @Bram28, did you mean this transformation is not correct? $a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}))=(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$

Comment: No, that transformation is fine, no matter if you treat the + as left or right associative.

Comment: @Bram28, I can not get where I got wrong. Could you please point out which transformations are wrong so that I can investigate them closer?

Comment: Hi @Bram28, Can you please specify where I'm treating $+$ as right-associative?

Comment: It is in that first step, going from $$a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$$ to $$a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+(a_k+a_{k+1}))...)$$. You say this is by inductive hypothesis, but by inductive hypothesis you get that $$a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_2+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}$$, so for the first equality to hold, that means you need to interpret $a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}$ as $a_3+(⋯+(a_k+a_{k+1})..)$, i.e. this step only works if you treat the + as right-associative

Comment: Hi @Bram28 my reasoning is as followed. From inductive hypothesis, I get $$a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_2+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}$$ Adding $a_1$ to both sides, I get  $$(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}))+a_1 = (a_2+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})+a_1$$ And we know that $x+y=y+x$, thus $$a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1}))= a_1+(a_2+a_3+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$$

Comment: Be careful with those parentheses!  Again, I am assuming that you are using the convention that $$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{n-1}+a_n$$ means  $$(((..(((a_1 + a_2) + a_3 ) + ... + a_{n-1}) + a_n$$, i.e. that you take the + to be left-associative. At least, that's what you indicated in the comments, and so that's what I used in my proof plan.  So, when you use the IH that $$a_2+(a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_2+a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}$$, what you have is that $$a_2+(((...(((a_3+a_4)...+a_k)+a_{k+1}) = (((...(((a_2+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1}$$

Comment: So,adding $a_1$ to that, you get: $$a_1+ (a_2+(((...(((a_3+a_4)...+a_k)+a_{k+1})) = a_1+(((...(((a_2+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1}$$, but you need to get to $$a_1+ (a_2+a_3+a_4...+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}$$, which is the same as $$a_1+ ((..((((a_2+a_3)+a_4)...+a_k)+a_{k+1}) = (((..(((a_1+a_2)+a_3)+...+a_k)+a_{k+1}$$  but which is not what you're getting.

Comment: @ElAnhDung I added the correct proof of the step of the Lemma to my post ...  in it, I explicitly go back and forth between the short-hand notation and showing where the actual parentheses are ... hope that helps clear up the confusion!

Comment: Hi @Bram28 I read through your proof of the lemma and completely agree with it. Honestly, I still can not understand where I'm wrong. You can see that I don't immediately go from $$a_2+(a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_2+a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}$$ to $$a_1+ (a_2+a_3+a_4...+a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_k+a_{k+1}$$ Instead, I go through more intermediate transformations. Please have a closer look on these transformations.

Comment: $$a_1+(a_2+⋯+a_k+a_{k+1})$$$$\overset{(1)}{=}a_1+(a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_{k+1}))$$$$\overset{(2)}{=}a_1+a_2+(a_3+⋯+a_{k+1})$$$$\overset{(3)}{=}(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+⋯+a_{k+1})$$$$\overset{(4)}{=}(a_1+a_2)+a_3+⋯+a_{k+1}$$$$\overset{(5)}{=}a_1+a_2+a_3+⋯+a_{k+1}$$

(1) Apply IH for $a_2,...,a_{k+1}$; (2) It's clear that $x+(y+z)=x+y+z$; (3) By our convention that $+$ is left-associative; (4) Apply IH for $(a_1+a_2),a_3,...,a_{k+1}$; (5) By our convention that $+$ is left-associative

Comment: Oh!!!  OK, now I see what's going on; thanks for the more detailed and organized proof, and it's indeed perfectly correct; my apologies for questioning it! Upvoting your answer now

Comment: Please don't mind @Bram28 ! I deeply appreciate your answer and enthusiastic replies :)

Comment: All right, cool! :)

Comment: @Bram28 If you don't mind, please check my proof in a closely related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867186/is-case-2-of-my-proof-that-sum-i-1n-a-i-sum-i-1n-a-sigmai-correct. I posted it 5 days ago and have yet got any attention. Thank you very much!