# Is Case 2 of my proof that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i)}$ correct?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, arithmetic

Let $I_n=\{i\in\mathbb N\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}$, $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ be a finite sequence in $\mathbb N$, and $\sigma$ be a permutation of $I_n$. I've shown that there is a sequence $(s_1,\cdots,s_n)$ such that $s_1=a_1$ and $s_{i+1}=s_i+a_{i+1}$ for all $1\leq i<n$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860987/how-to-justify-the-definition-of-summation-s-n-sum-i-1n-a-i-a-1-cdotsa-n). As a result, we write $s_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$, or $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. Prove that:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i)}$$

---

1. I'm not sure whether Case 2 where $\sigma(k+1)\leq k$ contains error, please help me check that Case.
2. Please suggest any shorter or simpler approach.

### My attempt:

I will prove this by induction on $n$. It's clear that the theorem is trivially true for $n=1$. Assume that the theorem is true for $n=k$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i=\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma(i)}$ where $\sigma$ is any permutation of $I_k$.

Let $\sigma'$ be any permutation of $I_{k+1}$. We have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)}$. There are two cases in total.

1. $\sigma'(k+1)=k+1$

As a result, $\{\sigma'(i)\mid 1\leq i\leq k\}=I_k$, then $\sigma'(i)\restriction_{I_k}$ is obviously a permutation of $I_k$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}\overset{IH}{=}\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+a_{k+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i$.

2. $\sigma'(k+1)\leq k$

As a result, there exists $y\leq k$ such that $\sigma'(y)=k+1$. We generate sequence $(b_i\mid 1\leq i\leq k)$ such that $b_i=a_{\sigma'(i)}$.

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\overset{IH}{=}\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k b_i+b_y=\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(y)}=\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{k+1}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)}=(\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{k+1})+a_{\sigma'(k+1)}\overset{Associativity}{=}\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+(a_{k+1}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)})\overset{Commutative}{=}\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+(a_{\sigma'(k+1)}+a_{k+1})\overset{Associativity}{=}(\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)})+a_{k+1}.$

Notice that $\{\sigma'(i)\mid 1\leq i\leq k\text{ and }i\neq y\}\cup\{\sigma'(k+1)\}=I_{k+1}\setminus\{k+1\}=I_{k}$. Thus $\sum_{i=1,i\neq y}^k a_{\sigma'(i)}+a_{\sigma'(k+1)}\overset{IH}{=}\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+a_{k+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i$.

To sum up, in either case, $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_{\sigma'(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i$. Hence the theorem is true for $n=k+1$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main doubt is for the $\sigma$ in the case of $k+1$, is it the same $\sigma$ for the case of $k$? Is the induction hypothesis valid since $\sigma$ is not a permutation of $I_k$?

One possible approach is note that permutation is a products of adjacent transposition so we can focus on proving that under adjacent transposition, the sum is preserved.

Suppose $\sigma$ only switches $j$ and $j+1$.

We have

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{j+1}a_{\sigma(i)}&=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}a_i + a_{j+1}\right) + a_{j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}a_i + (a_{j+1} + a_{j}), \text{Associativity}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} a_i +(a_j+a_{j+1}), \text{Commutative} \\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}a_i+a_j\right) + a_{j+1} , \text{Associativity}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{j+1}a_i\end{align}

Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i)}= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.

Hence the result is true by induction on the number of adjacent transposition.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my two issues. I have fixed the $1^{st}$ issue by using $\sigma$ for $I_k$ and $\sigma'$ for $I_{k+1}$. For the $2^{nd}$ issue, I'm finding way to get over. Since this is my very first exposure to advanced mathematics, I have not studied anything such as adjacent transposition in Linear Algebra. But I understood your proof plan: there is a finite number of adjacent transpositions to go from one permutation to another, and we know that the sum is preserved between them, so as between the first permutation and the last one.

Comment: I have just figured out how to tackle the second issue ^^ I will fix it tomorrow.

Comment: that's good news =)

Comment: I have fixed two mentioned issues. Please check my revised proof!

Comment: I think it looks fine :) you might like to highlight the place where you use commutative and associative properties of addition.

Comment: Many thanks for your dedicated help! I have edited my proof to signal where I use commutative and associative properties of addition. ^^